# Importing things from another location (java)

Tags: java, import

My school compiler says that JFrame is not accessible due to a restriction on the library when I use "import javax.swing.JFrame;". I can copy the contents of the library and move it to another location, but how do I import it from this new location?

Comment: JFrame is part of the JDK. You don't need any library to have it available. What "compiler" are you using, how, and what is the exact and complete message you get? You aren't doing an android application, are you?

Comment: I'm using eclipse on a school laptop and the file is restricted because there are blocks on it. I am able to move the file out of the blocked folder path, but do not know how to import the files because of their new location. (also im a noob at this)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "there is a block on it". I also have no idea of which file you're talking about. If it's a school laptop, go see your teacher and ask him if Eclipse it is configured correctly, explaining the problem you face.

Comment: Thanks for trying ;). I'll sort the problem out with my teacher's help.